# Excel - how to merge columns of data from consecutive rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a simple spreadsheet that has a large volume of data structured as such;

```
A1
   B2
      A3
         B4
```

- Going down several thousand rows.

I'd like to move all of column B into the blank cells of column A, keeping the same rows, so the data would become;

```
A1   A2   A3   A4
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? When moving the data it overwrites everything in column A

Comment: try to [**`Record a Macro`**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=recording+a+macro+in+excel) and post your code here. Explain what does not work the way you want and your attempts to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an option to do this with Paste Special. Just select column B, then right click column A and select Paste Special... > Paste Special... so that you get a pop up window with a lot of radio buttons in it. There is an option at the bottom "skip blanks" which does what you need. Activate this option and click ok.

Comment: @User2646560 if this answered your question you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Highlight and copy the desired data (horizontal or vertical).
- Left click the desired location to copy the data to.
- Right click >> Paste special.
- There are options there like skip blanks or transpose which may be useful.